# How to Change Weeknumbers background color in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar

I am not able to change the weeknumbers style in FullCalendar.

I have turned on the `WeekNumbers: true` and also added the following style in CSS file:

```css
.fc-week-number {
   background-color: red !important;
   color: #ee0726;
}
```

It does not work.

Answer (score 0):

In fullCalendar 6 the correct class name is `fc-daygrid-week-number`, so you need to write something like

```
.fc-daygrid-week-number {
   background-color: red !important;
   color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

Live demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/ZEPJwMW

Note that this only affects the `dayGridMonth` view - other views render the week number differently.